# Constructing a vector space of 8 elements from the field of 2 elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I would like to use the field of 2 elements ($\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) to construct a vector space consisting of 8 elements.

I have succeeded in constructing vector spaces of 2 elements and 4 elements but I don't see how it is possible to create an 8 element set of vectors that is closed under addition.

My result for a vector space of two elements is
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix} \right\}
$$

and for a vector space of four elements,
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix} \right\}.
$$
Is it possible to create a vector space with 8 elements and, if so, what would it be?

Comment: Use three coordinates.

Comment: Are there even 8 elements in the *field*?

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics Not sure you understood the question.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I did not, apparently. I assumed it had to be two dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a field known as $\mathbb Z_2$ (amongst other things) which has two elements $0,1$ (or odd, even if you want to be quirky).

A vector space over a field can have any dimension you like - don't be misled by the $2$ to think that there can only be two components to each vector. Think about a vector in $3$-dimensional space (where the real numbers are the ground field).

Because $8=2^3$ you need the vector space to have dimension $3$, and therefore there will be at least $3$ components.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I believe I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb F_8$ is a vector space of dimension  $3$ over its prime subfield $\mathbb F_2$ (as any finite field  $\mathbb F_{p^n} $ can be thought of as an $n $ dimensional vector space over  $\mathbb Z_p $).

Answer (score 0):

All vector spaces of $8$ elements over $F_2$ look the same: they're all isomorphic to $F_2\times F_2\times F_2$.

Your first example is isomorphic to $F_2$ itself by mapping the zero element to the zero vector and the $1$ element to the $1$'s vector.

Your second set is just plainly $F_2\times F_2$.

In general, any $F_2$ vector space of order $2^n$ is just $F_2^n$.